# how to increase the screen resolution?

Tags: resolution

I installed Ubuntu in my Lenovo ThinkPad X60. Currently the screen resolution is set to 1024x768, which is the maximum resolution in the settings. Is it the hardware maximum resolution?

Compared to what has been in Windows XP, everything looks so big. How can I make them all small?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maximum resolution for ThinkPad X60 is 1024x768, so you can't increase it.

You can change size of the text, that could help.

Run "Appearance" (if you have classic desktop, then from menu **System → Preferences → Appearance**, if you have Unity then run ** Dash** (Ubuntu button in top left corner) and search for "Appearance"). Navigate to **Fonts** where you can set size of all system fonts (or click on **Details...** to set DPI for whole system).

Answer (score 0):

While it's correct that you cannot get more than 1024x768 on the laptop's screen, it really has to be mentioned that you can get a **much higher resolution** if you connect to an external monitor simply using a VGA cable.

E.g. I am on 1920x1080 right now on an X60; To further back this up, check the specs for the **GMA950 graphics chipset** that X60 comes with http://www.intel.com/products/chipsets/gma950/ and you'll see it can go all the way up to **2048x1536 @75Hz**.

Other than the above, if you happen to have a monitor with a non-VGA reception, you can always get a VGA to DVI/HDMI convertor to connect the different cables, however I've noticed that in the case of using a VGA to HDMI conversion box the resolution does not get higher than 1024x768 as it does not recognize the monitor.

Lastly, in my case I had to disable the X60's native monitor output when connecting to an external monitor, as having them both on at the same time made the visual experience quite sluggish, while just having the external monitor on was with no probs at all.

Comment: A bit of additional trivia, the X60 I got is the FSF approved X60 from gluglug as per http://www.fsf.org/news/gluglug-x60-laptop-now-certified-to-respect-your-freedom , which makes it pretty much the only fully free-as in freedom- laptop one can currently get.